# Build web page request in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-chrome, rest

I'm building a native application. The app has an embedded webview (UIWebView) pointing to a social website. To be able to use the website inside the app, user has to log in by the webview (username/password) and then he can continue use the site with saved cookies. Normally, the cookies expire after two days. After that, the user has to re-login by the webview.

Now suppose I know username and password of the user and I would like to make the user login automatically with this account when the cookie expires. How can I do that?

I tried to simulate the Login action when I click on Login button on web page, but not successful.By using "Inspect Element" of Chrome, I can see Chrome makes a "Post" request to an URL with some parameters. However, the request doesn't get successful (I use REST client for testing).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the solution. I didn't build requests anymore. I used javascript to set text fields and make "click" action on the webview. Done.